# C++ ignoring the first character

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a text file (text.txt) that contains

```
1. One
2. Two
3. Three
4. Four
5. Five
6. Six
```

However it's ignoring the first character and giving me the following output.

```
1. One
 Three
 Five
 Two
 Six
 Four
```

It ignores the numbers. My program reads the input file to an array and randomly spits out the items in the array. It works but it doesn't print out the numbers. How should I fix this?

Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 6;
    //random seeding
    srand(time(0));
    std::string myArray[arraySize];
    std::ifstream inFile("text.txt");

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < arraySize && std::getline(inFile, myArray[i++]))
        {
            inFile >> myArray[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        int index = rand() % arraySize;
        //swap myArray[i] with myArray[index]
        std::string temp = myArray[i];
        myArray[i] = myArray[index];
        myArray[index] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do `i++` in the loop body rather than in the condition of the `while`.

Comment: You fix this by running the debugger and observing the values of all variables in your program, as they change, while you use your debugger to run your program one line at a time. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. I'm confident that you will be able to easily figure out this simple bug, in your code, with your debugger. It's always better, in the long run, to learn how to debug one's own code, instead of posting a question to a web site every time you can't figure out the bug by looking at the code.

Comment: @0x499602D2 that will make it worse.

Comment: @MarkRansom I see

Comment: Just get rid of `inFile >> myArray[i];`.  The call to `getline` does everything you want.

Comment: debugging(or `cout`) every `myArray` values in while loop right after `getline` and `>>` operator will be helpful.

Comment: If you have trouble debugging this code, try simplifying it. For example, randomly scrambling the output is an extra step -- don't try to do that until the basic reading and writing works.

Answer (score 0):

At the first iteration (`i = 0`), you get the first line using `getline` and assign it to `myArray[0]`, and immediately increnent the variable `i`. Now `i` is equal to `1`. Then you enter the `while` loop, and read the second line using `>>` operator, until reaching to the first whitespace, and assign it to `myArray[1]`.

In the next iteration on the `while` loop (`i` is still `1`), you read the remaining characters of the second line and assign it to `myArray[1]`; This is the reason that the number is ommited. Then you increase `i` to `2` and the pattern will be occurred until the end of the loop.

You don't need the `inFile >> myArray[i];` line; Using `getline` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing more than you think you are in your `while` loop.

`std::getline(inFile, myArray[i++])` actually does everything you need.
`getline()` reads a complete line of text from the input stream, up to a newline character (the newline is excluded from the output).

The `>>` operator reads data from a stream up to **any whitespace character, newlines included**. So, this line:

`inFile >> myArray[i];`

reads one word from your file (in this case the number at the beginning of the line) and leaves the rest behind, whitespace included. When the loop continues, `getline()` reads the rest of the line. Because `i` is not incremented until **after** this, the rest of the line is copied to the same array element that the number was in, overwriting it as a completely new string.

The first line, '1. One', is correct because when `getline()` first reads from the file, the input stream is at the very beginning. The body of your loop hasn't executed yet. Then, `i` increments and your program reads the first "word" on the second line (`2.`), which is subsequently overwritten with `Two` when the loop runs again.

The solution, then,  is to leave your `while` loop with an empty body, like this:

```
while (i < arraySize && std::getline(inFile, myArray[i++]))
{
    ;
}
```

Or move the call to `getline()` into the body of the loop and out of the conditional statement:

```
while (i < arraySize)
{
    std::getline(inFile, myArray[i++]);
}
```